# Using pressure transducers and air pumps with arduino

Tags: arduino, air-pressure

I am trying to create an pneumatic system where the Arduino board can both pump air and work as a vacuum. I am confused as to what exactly an pressure transducer can do. As far as I know, a transducer converts energy from one form(pressure in this case) to another - electrical signal. I have seen a video where the person said they were using the tranducer as a vacuum?

I initially was planning on using an [air pump motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FHAEFD6) and I was told for the whole system to work I would need to sense the air pressure. Can I combine the pump motor with a transducer? How about a [pressure sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JP4Y7S8)?

Comment: The type of pump you've  linked to actually creates rather a small amount of pressure. It only needs to create enough  to overcome the water inside the submerged tube.

There's no reason  that you can't use some of your I/O to talk to the sensor and some of the rest of it to turn on your air-pump.

Answer (score 0):

A pressure transducer senses pressure and converts that to an electrical value. The electrical value can be voltage versus pressure, current versus pressure (4mA to 20mA), or a digital output (e.g., I2C). Most pressure transducers are either for vacuum or pressure use (one or the other, not both). There are compound pressure transducers that will measure from negative (usually -15psi) to positive pressure. [Omega](https://www.omega.com/en-us/pressure-measurement/pressure-transducers/px309/p/PX309-015CGV) has such a pressure transducer, or you can look to see what hobbyist-friendly distributors like Adafruit, Digi-Key, or Mouser carry. You'll need to select the upper maximum pressure you wish to measure.

The air pump you linked to is for aerating aquariums. It will not create much pressure or vacuum. What sort of pressure range do you need?